# Javascript get child element from one div and transfer element data into another div

Tags: javascript

I have a box called "out" and a box called "deposit". All i am trying to do is transfer any child element of the box "out" into the box "deposit" using an onclick command.

```
<div id="out">
<span>qwe</span>
<h1>asd</h1>
<img src="img/globe.png"/>
<img src="img/sdf.jpg"  />
<b>test</b>
</div>

<div id="deposit"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

document.getElementById('out').onclick = function() { 

document.getElementById('deposit').innerHTML=document.getElementById('out').getElementsByTagName('*').innerHTML;

}

</script>
```

I boiled down the problem to it having to do with the "getElementsByTagName" issue. Getchildnodes, children, and this getelementsbytagname got me confused. All I'm trying to do is simply clicking on any element in the "out" box and simply transferring the selected element into the "deposit" box.

[No jquery please, i need to solve this the regular way.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

`document.getElementById('deposit').innerHTML=document.getElementById('out').getElementsByTagName('*').innerHTML;`

with

```
var a = document.getElementById('out');

for (var i = 0; i < a.childNodes.length; i++) {
    a.childNodes[i].onclick = function () {

        var b = document.getElementById('deposit');
        b.innerHTML = b.innerHTML + this.outerHTML;

    }
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VtUaf/5)**

Comment: I tried it, but i keep getting the same error saying "undefined"

Comment: Now it does give me the first element but is followed by 4 'undefined's which probably stand for the other 4 child elements

Comment: Yea, it does transfer all of the elements, but it doesn't transfer the one i specifically click on. So if i clicked on the <span> it would only transfer span, but if i clicked on img it would only transfer img. That's the part i'm having trouble with

Comment: Do you think the function should start with, instead of "out".onclick = function with something like "out".any_child_element_of_"out".onclick = function ( then your function?)

Comment: I think it's getting closer, watch, i did the following and it works for the first element only though:

Comment: I did this: 
document.getElementById('out').firstChild.onclick = function() { 

var b = document.getElementById('deposit');
b.innerHTML = b.innerHTML + this.outerHTML;
} BUT it only works for the first child element, i am trying to make it work for all

Comment: Thanks, i was thinking of looping through it but you beat me to it! Thanks for help!

Comment: @sadelectron Yeah, right before you posted 'first element' I posted answer :P